# Contradiction about the direction of magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, charge, inductance

I have encountered two contradictory directions for the force felt by current in a wire immersed in a uniform magnetic field.

Halliday says the force should be to the left in the situation pictured below, as the **current** is moving upwards.

Hyperphysics, however, says that the force due to a **charge**-length element should be downwards because the charge is moving with a certain velocity!

Both of these make sense, yet they contradict each other. Please help.

[image: Halliday 8th ed]

[image: Hyperphysics]

Comment: The second diagram is looking at the force that causes the current flow.  the first diagram is looking at the forced caused by the current flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Halliday says the force should be to the left in the situation pictured below, as the current is moving upwards.

The author wants to say that the net force on the vertical wire is towards left.

> Hyperphysics, however, says that the force due to a charge-length element should be downwards because the charge is moving with a certain velocity!

The concerned website wants to say that the force on the charge is in downward direction.

Both sources are saying correct but I think that you misunderstood the concepts.The first source is saying about net force on wire while the second source is talking about the net force on individual charges which are two different aspects.

Comment: No, Halliday is saying the vertical strand of wire is feeling a force to the left, and the horizontal wires are feeling upward and downward forces which cancel each other out.


Hyperphysics is saying that every charge in the wire is feeling a downward force, creating a net downward force.

Comment: @Pixel S is it correct now

Comment: @PixelS The second case addresses the force on the charges in the wire.  That force is downwards, and generates a clockwise current.  The force on the *wire* due to the motion of those charges in the B field is to the left.  Although the alignment in the two cases is different, in both cases the force opposes the motion of the wire loop.

Comment: Thank you both.

Answer (score -1):

I think both are correct. Rotate the diagram by 180 degree and think. Magnetic fields applied are also opposite to each other.